# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'BigAutoField'

Tags: python, django

so i'm following the Django project in the textbook "Python crash course 2nd ed" and i'm into the mapping URLS section for those who know, and  when i try my system cant seem to runserver anymore, i'm encountering the following error: AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'BigAutoField'

if anyone can help, it would be great, thanks already. i'm fairly new to django and trying my way around it but i don't really know what or where to find the error..

it worked actually fine before i added the two urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls'), name='learning_logs'),
]
```

and

```
"""Defines url patterns for learning_logs."""

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page.
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

the models.py is

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        """return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.text 
                     
class Entry(models.Model):
    """something specific learned about a topic"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):  
        """return a string representation of the model"""
        if len(self.text) >= 50:
            return f"{self.text[:50]}..."
        else:
            return "..."
```

Comment: You might have forgotten to run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: Could you show us your models.py?

Comment: earlier it said that i was running django=3.2.8 but now when i pip freeze i see that i'm on Django==1.8.6

Comment: Then it is the version you have to change...

Answer (score 0):

It is the version you have to change.
Django 1.8 does not have `BigAutoField`.

[Here's url to  Django 1.8 doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/)

Comment: thank you! it was simple as that! i feel dumb haha, do you know why it changed its version out of nowhere?

Comment: Django 1.8 was released in April 2015, 6 1/2 years ago. How old is your system? It's possible you installed it a long time ago, didn't do much with it, and now your project found that installation? But that would require using a really old version of Python as well. What version of Python are you currently using?